# Identify the page I am viewing

Tags: footer

I am using a theme which on the whole is great. However it has footer widgets and I only want them displayed on the home page rather than all of them. So what I would like to do is simply miss this section of code found in the footer.php if the page is any page other than home.

```
<div class="footer-widgets">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('site-footer') ?>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`is_home()` will do just exactly that. It returns true on the home page and false on any other page. Your solution will be to completely wrap your code above in an `is_home()` conditional

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    // Your in question comes here
}
```